# Как в CSS сделать тень только в одну сторону

Tags: css, box-shadow

Как в CSS задать тень блоку, чтобы она была только с одной стороны?
Пример: есть блок, нужно задать ему некую тень справа. Тень должна быть с правой стороны и не должна уходить за верхнюю и нижнюю стороны блока.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115427/how-can-i-add-a-box-shadow-on-one-side-of-an-element

Comment: @Hikikomori спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не указать размытие, то так и будет. Но это уже не тень а ближе к бордеру что-то получиться.

В любых остальных случаях такое не получиться. Как тень может быть в природе только с одной стороны к примеру куба? По бокам в любом случае есть его рассеивание.

Может покажете дизайн того, что хотите получить?